# Updating Google Play Services in lib module

Tags: android, google-play-services

Updating old project's Google Play Services plugin to
`com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0`, 
I'm running into the following problem:

My project has a lib module shared by other app modules, whose gradle build file is:

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 22
        versionName "2.11"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.0.1'
}
```

---

When building the project, I get the following errors:

```
Error:(54, 41) error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not exist

Error:(770, 19) error: cannot find symbol class LatLng
```

Reverting to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.0.0'
```

Everything works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the LatLng class has moved to a new location.  Add the following to your build file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
```

This will download the component containing that class and your compilation should succeed.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks